# Fix zoom level between two Marker in Google-Map

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

Currently I work with **Google-Map-v2** and I want to show Direction between two *Markers*. Everything is ok and direction between two *Markers* calculate and draw fine.But only one problem is remain.

The problem is Zoom level between these two markers in Google-Map is too much. I Search in SO and find a solution for changing Zoom Level by Following code :

```
 LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
    builder.include(origin);
    builder.include(dest);
    LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();

    CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 50);
    mMap.animateCamera(cu);
```

Now it's better But still zoom level is not good. Is it possible to do some fixes on Code ? ( if I can some padding to view is fixed )

I Also change 50 to 6,12,... But nothing changed.

Comment: update zoom level in CameraUpdate instance and update map

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are using the correct code, and the value (50) needs to be increased if you want to zoom less (be outer) or decreased to 0 if you want to be in the smallest area containing the two markers (you can skip the value in case).

If you set a value of 150 or more, and the level is too much you can use the animation callback to zoom out after the `LatLng` zoom:

[Google API](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#animateCamera(com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate)
com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.CancelableCallback)

```
LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
builder.include(origin);
builder.include(dest);
LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();

CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 50);
mMap.animateCamera(cu, new GoogleMap.CancelableCallback(){
    void onCancel(){}
    void onFinish(){
        CameraUpdate zout = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomBy(-3.0);
        mMap.animateCamera(zout);
    }
});
```

This should zoom to the `LatLng` and when finished, zoom back of 3 levels.

Comment: what is 50 padding? is it offset in pixels or what?

Comment: And how to set padding correctly to always see both markers on the map? Because based on the distance between points it can be different value as I understand

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
 CameraPosition cameraPosition =
                                    new CameraPosition.Builder()
                                            .target(yourlatlng)
                                           // .bearing(targetBearing)// you can ignore it
                                            .zoom(12)// your zoom value
                                                    // .tilt(40)  // angle of view
                                            .build();


                            mMap.animateCamera(
                                    CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition),
                                    500,
                                    null);
```

Comment: How can I found my zoom level is proper ? for example in my response sometimes our path between two cities and sometimes between two country and when I set zoom(12) is it return goodCameraPosition ?

Comment: you can check distance b/w current location and destination and based on that set the zoom level.